# Is there an R function to make x rows equal to a specific row and repeat the operation?

Tags: r

everyone!

Being a beginner with the R software (I think my request is feasible on this software), I would like to ask you a question.

In a large Excel type file, I have a column where the values I am interested in are only every 193 lines. So I would like the previous 192 rows to be equal to the value of the 193rd position ... and so on for all 193 rows, until the end of the column.

Concretely, here is what I would like to get for this little example:

```html
Month    Fund_number    Cluster_ref_INPUT      Expected_output
1        1              1                      1
2        1              1                      1
3        1              3                      1
4        1              1                      1
1        3              2                      NA
2        3              NA                     NA
3        3              NA                     NA
4        3              NA                     NA
1        8              4                      5
2        8              5                      5
3        8              5                      5
4        8              5                      5
```

The column "Cluster_ref_INPUT" is partitioned according to the column "Fund_number" (one observation for each fund every month for 4 months). The values that interest me in the INPUT column appear every 4 observations (the value in the 4th month).

Thus, we can see that for each fund number, we find in the column "Expected_output" the values corresponding to the value found in the last line of the column "Cluster_ref_INPUT". (every 4 lines). I think we should partition by "Fund_number" and put that all the lines are equal to the last one... something like that?

Do you have any idea what code I should use to make this work?

I hope that's clear enough. Do not hesitate if I need to clarify.

Thank you very much in advance,

Vanie

Comment: Why can't you just subset according to `df[df$Month == 4, ]`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one line solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

exdata <- fread(text = "
  Month    Fund_number    Cluster_ref_INPUT      Expected_output
  1        1              1                      1
  2        1              1                      1
  3        1              3                      1
  4        1              1                      1
  1        2              2                      NA
  2        2              NA                     NA
  3        2              NA                     NA
  4        2              NA                     NA
  1        3              4                      5
  2        3              5                      5
  3        3              5                      5
  4        3              5                      5")
# You can read you data directly as data.table using fread or convert using setDT(exdata)

exdata[, newvar := Cluster_ref_INPUT[.N], by = Fund_number]

> exdata
    Month Fund_number Cluster_ref_INPUT Expected_output newvar
 1:     1           1                 1               1      1
 2:     2           1                 1               1      1
 3:     3           1                 3               1      1
 4:     4           1                 1               1      1
 5:     1           2                 2              NA     NA
 6:     2           2                NA              NA     NA
 7:     3           2                NA              NA     NA
 8:     4           2                NA              NA     NA
 9:     1           3                 4               5      5
10:     2           3                 5               5      5
11:     3           3                 5               5      5
12:     4           3                 5               5      5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably solutions using `tidyverse` that'll be a lot faster, but here's a solution in `base` R.

```
#Your data
df <- data.frame(Month = rep_len(c(1:4), 12), 
                 Fund_number = rep(c(1:3), each = 4), 
                 Cluster_ref_INPUT = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, 5), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Create an empty data frame in which the results will be stored
outdat <- data.frame(Month = c(), Fund_number = c(), Cluster_ref_INPUT = c(), expected_input = c(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Using a for loop
#Iterate through the list of unique Fund_number values
for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Fund_number))){

  #Subset data pertaining to each unique Fund_number
  curdat <- subset(df, df$Fund_number == unique(df$Fund_number)[i])

  #Take the value of Cluster_ref_Input from the last row
  #And set it as the value for expected_input column for all rows
  curdat$expected_input <- curdat$Cluster_ref_INPUT[nrow(curdat)]

  #Append this modified subset to the output container data frame
  outdat <- rbind(outdat, curdat)

  #Go to next iteration
}

#Remove non-essential looping variables
rm(curdat, i)

outdat
#    Month Fund_number Cluster_ref_INPUT expected_input
# 1      1           1                 1              1
# 2      2           1                 1              1
# 3      3           1                 3              1
# 4      4           1                 1              1
# 5      1           2                 2             NA
# 6      2           2                NA             NA
# 7      3           2                NA             NA
# 8      4           2                NA             NA
# 9      1           3                 4              5
# 10     2           3                 5              5
# 11     3           3                 5              5
# 12     4           3                 5              5
```

**EDIT: additional solutions + benchmarking**

Per OP's comment on this answer, I've presented some faster solutions (`dplyr` and the `data.table` solution from the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996513/9494044) answer) and also benchmarked them on a 950,004 row simulated dataset similar to the one in OP's example. Code and results below; the entire code-block can be copy-pasted and run directly as long as the necessary libraries (`microbenchmark`, `dplyr`, `data.table`) and their dependencies are installed. (If someone knows a solution based on `apply()` they're welcome to add it here.)

```
rm(list = ls())

#Library for benchmarking
library(microbenchmark)

#Dplyr
library(dplyr)

#Data.table
library(data.table)

#Your data
df <- data.frame(Month = rep_len(c(1:12), 79167), 
                 Fund_number = rep(c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 22), each = 158334), 
                 Cluster_ref_INPUT = sample(letters, size = 950004, replace = TRUE), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Data in format for data.table
df_t <- data.table(Month = rep_len(c(1:12), 79167), 
                   Fund_number = rep(c(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 22), each = 158334), 
                   Cluster_ref_INPUT = sample(letters, size = 950004, replace = TRUE), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#----------------

#Base R solution


#Using a for loop
#Iterate through the list of unique Fund_number values
base_r_func <- function(df) {
  #Create an empty data frame in which the results will be stored
  outdat <- data.frame(Month = c(), 
                       Fund_number = c(), 
                       Cluster_ref_INPUT = c(), 
                       expected_input = c(), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Fund_number))){

  #Subset data pertaining to each unique Fund_number
  curdat <- subset(df, df$Fund_number == unique(df$Fund_number)[i])

  #Take the value of Cluster_ref_Input from the last row
  #And set it as the value for expected_input column for all rows
  curdat$expected_input <- curdat$Cluster_ref_INPUT[nrow(curdat)]

  #Append this modified subset to the output container data frame
  outdat <- rbind(outdat, curdat)

  #Go to next iteration
  }
  #Remove non-essential looping variables
  rm(curdat, i)

  #This return is needed for the base_r_func function wrapper
  #this code is enclosed in (not necessary otherwise)
  return(outdat)
}



#----------------

#Tidyverse solution

dplyr_func <- function(df){
  df %>% #For actual use, replace this %>% with %<>%
         #and it will write the output back to the input object
    #Group the data by Fund_number
    group_by(Fund_number) %>%
    #Create a new column populated w/ last value from Cluster_ref_INPUT
    mutate(expected_input = last(Cluster_ref_INPUT))
}

#----------------

#Data table solution

dt_func <- function(df_t){

  #For this function, we are using
  #dt_t (created above)

  #Logic similar to dplyr solution
  df_t <- df_t[ , expected_output := Cluster_ref_INPUT[.N], by = Fund_number]

}

dt_func_conv <- function(df){

  #Converting data.frame to data.table format
  df_t <- data.table(df)

  #Logic similar to dplyr solution
  df_t <- df_t[ , expected_output := Cluster_ref_INPUT[.N], by = Fund_number]
}

#----------------

#Benchmarks

bm_vals <- microbenchmark(base_r_func(df), 
                          dplyr_func(df),
                          dt_func(df_t),
                          dt_func_conv(df), times = 8)

bm_vals
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   base_r_func(df) 618.58202 702.30019 721.90643 743.02018 754.87397 756.28077     8
#    dplyr_func(df) 119.18264 123.26038 128.04438 125.64418 133.37712 140.60905     8
#     dt_func(df_t)  38.06384  38.27545  40.94850  38.88269  43.58225  48.04335     8
#  dt_func_conv(df)  48.87009  51.13212  69.62772  54.36058  57.68829 181.78970     8

#----------------
```

As can be seen, using `data.table` would be the way to go if speed is a necessity. `data.table` is faster than `dplyr` and `base R` even when the overhead of converting a regular `data.frame` to a `data.table` is considered (see results of `dt_func_conv()`).

**Edit:** following up on Carlos Eduardo Lagosta's comments, using `setDT()` to coerce the `df` from a `data.frame` to a `data.table`, makes the overhead of said coercion close to nil. Code snippet and benchmark values below.

```
#This version includes the time taken
#to coerce a data.frame to a data.table
dt_func_conv <- function(df){

  #Logic similar to dplyr solution
  #setDT() coerces data.frames to the data.table format
  setDT(df)[ , expected_output := Cluster_ref_INPUT[.N], by = Fund_number]

}

bm_vals
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   base_r_func(df) 271.60196 344.47280 353.76204 348.53663 368.65696 435.16163     8
#    dplyr_func(df) 121.31239 122.67096 138.54481 128.78134 138.72509 206.69133     8
#     dt_func(df_t)  38.21601  38.57787  40.79427  39.53428  43.14732  45.61921     8
#  dt_func_conv(df)  41.11210  43.28519  46.72589  46.74063  50.16052  52.32235     8
```

**For the OP specifically:** whatever solution you wish to use, the code you're looking for is within the body of the corresponding function. So, for instance, if you want to use the `dplyr` solution, you would need to take this code and tailor it to your data objects:

```
df %>% #For actual use, replace this %>% with %<>%
         #and it will write the output back to the input object
    #Group the data by Fund_number
    group_by(Fund_number) %>%
    #Create a new column populated w/ last value from Cluster_ref_INPUT
    mutate(expected_input = last(Cluster_ref_INPUT))
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much @Dubois for answering me. Your code works perfectly for the example I posted. However, I have 2 problems applying it to my real Excel file (in the data frame presentation). First, contrary to the example, in my real file, some "Fund_number" are not present between the 1st and the last (no fund 5 or 8 between 1 and 10 for example). I modified my example above. Secondly, concerning the elements of the "Cluster_ref_INPUT" column, how can I write the data frame otherwise (don't write the values one by one) because my file contains more than 950000 lines?

Comment: @VanieButil I've updated the answer with additional solutions and benchmarked them. Addressing your questions here: it doesn't matter if `Fund_number` is not a continuous sequence, the code will work all the same. And 950,000 lines of data is not much of an issue either. Even the slowest solution presented here (my original `for loop`) still completes in less than a second (see benchmarks in the answer). If speed is what you are after, I would advise using the `data.table` solution.

Comment: Just a comment on the speed of converting to data.table. Much of the difference in `dt_func_conv` is because you create a new object. Try using setDT() instead. A data.table is just a data.frame with an extra class identifier.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta thank you! I have only ever used `data.table` in passing, so this is good to know. I've updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Here's the trick: setDT change by reference, without copy, and a data.table is still a data.frame. There's no need to copy to a new object (`df_t <- setDT(df)`). Just use `setDT(df)`.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta it's not being copied there. That's a typo I forgot to remove. Thanks for catching that!